# Best practice to plot 3D geometry figure

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

I want to plot something like this? But the tools I found is not so convenient to plot such figure.

Specifically, I want to draw some 3D shape (eg f(x,y) and tangent plane at some points, and some latex math text to explain). I use python a lot, it is very difficult to use the popular matplotlib to plot such figures? I also know a little about tikz, it can generate high quality figures, but writing tikz code is not so friendly.

[image]

The source for the figure, [link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Vector_Calculus_(Corral)/02%3A_Functions_of_Several_Variables/2.03%3A_Tangent_Plane_to_a_Surface)

Comment: Try the 3D plot in GeoGebra. You can add LaTeX to the figure and export the graphic in several formats. You can animate your figure too if required.

Comment: @Paul Thx, I have tried the GeoGebra tool. I think it is the best tool I have used for plotting such figures.

Comment: If you want a piece of a plane you can put in 4 points of the plane A,B,C,D then join them with the polygon command polygon(A,B,C,D) then hide the points.